# Realloc trouble

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I have problem.
I have stroke: "/hello/world"
I need to copy word 'hello' to another string;

I have this code:

```
void copy(char *command) {// copy 
 char *word = NULL;
 int size = 1;
 if (*command == '/') {
    command++;
    while (*command != '/') {
         word = (char*)realloc(word, size * sizeof(char));
         *word = *command;
         size++;
         word++;
         command++;
     }
     printf("%s", word);
     free(word);
}
```

but I get this error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

What I do wrong?

Comment: `word++` that is wrong. `realloc` requires the same pointer that was returned from a previous `malloc` or `realloc` call as the first arg. By incrementing the pointer you lose the original pointer. As for the segementation fault it is likely because you have not NUL terminated your string.

Comment: The best way to debug this problem and most other bugs is to use a debugger. At a minimum the debugger will tell you immediately exactly which line of code triggers the seg fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @kaylum says the reason that you get the error is that you change the `word` pointer's value. When you reallocate memory for a allocated array of memory block and change the size of that memory block's size, `realloc()` changes the size and returns the pointer which points to first memory block of that allocated array. In this case if you want to change size of `word`'s memory try using an index to access the newly added memory block.

```
    void copy(char *command) {// copy
      char *word = NULL;
      printf("%s\n",command);
      int size = 1,index=0;``
      if (*command == '/') {
        command++;
        while (*command != '/') {
          word = (char*)realloc(word, size * sizeof(char));
          word[index] = *command;
          size++;
          command++;
          index++;
        }
        printf("%s\n", word);
        free(word);
      }
    }
```

Comment: it's better to add `word[index]='\0'` after while loop.anyway I really liked this code.

Comment: `printf("%s\n", word);` leads to UB as `word` does not point to a _string_.  Lack of `'\0'`.  Allocation not big enough for it too.

Comment: @hanie @chux  yes it should add `'\0'` after the for loop, to make it a string.

Comment: `word` should be reallocated to `size+1` bytes to allow for the null terminator, and you must set the null terminator before passing `word` to `printf` for the `%s` conversion.